# Connect to FTP Server with .net 2.0

Tags: vb.net, open-source, .net-2.0, ftp

I'm looking to connect to an existing FTP server, upload a file, wait while the server generates a report on it, and download that report back to the local machine in a VB.NET 2.0 WinForms project.

Is there an existing FTP library that would be helpful to me for this?  My task seems simple enough that I'd rather not get into the world of active vs. passive, sockets, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Net.FtpWebRequest and System.Net.WebClient can both do this.

WebClient is simpler but supports less features. I haven't run into many situations that FtpWebRequest can't handle.

Answer (score 4):

Look into System.Net.[FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(loband).aspx)/[FtpWebResonse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse(loband).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the FtpWebRequest class

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx