# FTP Upload download using dot net 2.0

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp

Need to upload and download files to and from a FTP server Synchronously using vb.net, any sample code will be helpful

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782992/connect-to-ftp-server-with-net-2-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the best possible example

http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_ftp_upload.html

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) shows samples of how to download, upload, and delete files on a server, using VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [FTP Client written in VB.NET by Paul Kimmell](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/vb_internet/html/article.php/c8459__1/) before with success.